# Append HTML with Google Map Marker Icon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am working on weather website.

I am using [Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) as backbone.

I am marking the major cities of country with Marker.

Depending upon the weather type like sunny, partly_cloudy I am changing the marker image.

Now with marker image I want to show a div with current temperature.

My plan was to append some  with marker image but I was not able to achieve this.

Help me folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display custom made div's on the map using custom overlays.

Check the [google map api documentation about the topic](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays)

[Marker Light - Markers on a diet](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) has a good example of custom layers using the version 2 of the api. I couldn't manage to find good examples for the 3rd version.

Comment: I want to add HTML in overlays. I didnt find anything in the documentation regarding this

Comment: onAdd function is where you will be creating html elements using javascript, then by using the draw function you calculate the position to place your main div element

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://blog.mridey.com/2009/09/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html) out. I've found it very usefull and it's for v3 :)